# Unable to change the default CQ login page

Tags: aem

I would to change the default login page (to `/content/ethz_ch/Login`)

I configured tha page by the *Day CQ Login Selector Authentication Handler*

[image]

In `./launchpad/config/com/day/cq/auth/impl/LoginSelectorHandler.config` I see

```
auth.loginselector.defaultloginpage="/content/ethz_ch/Login"
```

as expected.

I then configured a test page (`/content/ethz_ch/de/auth_test.html`) with a closed user group and left the login page field blank.

When accessing the test page, instead on the newly defined login page I am redirected to

```
https://..../system/sling/cqform/defaultlogin.html?resource=%2Fcontent%2Fethz_ch%2Fde%2Fauth_test.html&$$login$$=%24%24login%24%24
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Day CQ Login Selector Authentication Handler* there is a **Path Info** setting which restricts the possible login pages:

> A list of request extensions indicating requests for which the Login Selector Authentication Handler may request credentials. Any request whose extension is not one the listed extensions will not cause the credentials to be requested. If this list is empty the default list of html and htm is used. Note that the list entries must not have leading dots. Requests without extension or requests with trailing slashes (/) are always handled by the Login Selector Authentication Handler regardless of this configuration.

Specifying the **Default Login Page** with the full URL (with extension) solved the problem:

```
/content/ethz_ch/login.html
```